# jQuery sortable (an empty string)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

**html**

```
<ul id="user-stream-list" class="user-stream-list ui-sortable">
    <li data-id="36" data-oid="0" class="feed" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="cat-title" data-title="36">Tech Crunch<span class="edit-title" style="right: 35px;">rename</span><span class="delete-title">×</span></span>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="37" data-oid="1" class="feed" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="cat-title" data-title="37">Apple<span class="edit-title">rename</span></span>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="18" data-fid="11" href="http://appleinsider.com/appleinsider.rss"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=appleinsider.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">AppleInsider - Frontpage News</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="11" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$( "#user-stream-list" ).sortable({
        update : function () {
            var order = $('#user-stream-list').sortable('serialize');
            console.log(order);
            //$("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
        }
    });
```

**DB**

```
 id     uid     oid     cname 
 20     36       0      Tech Crunch
 21     37       1      Apple
```

When I rearrange the following my console.log() returns `(an empty string)` I'm clueless with why its not showing anything. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9XgA/)

Im trying to pass the data-id and data-oid so that in php i can tie up the two for processing to my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the id's of the elements does not follow the required format, the id should have two parts separated by an underscore, equal sign or hyphen

[From Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize)

> Note: If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id
>   attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form:
>   "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes "foo_1",
>   "foo_5", "foo_2" will serialize to "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2". You can
>   use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and
>   number. For example "foo=1", "foo-1", and "foo_1" all serialize to
>   "foo[]=1".

ex

```
<ul id="user-stream-list" class="user-stream-list ui-sortable">
    <li id="o_36" class="feed" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="cat-title" data-title="36">Tech Crunch<span class="edit-title" style="right: 35px;">rename</span><span class="delete-title">×</span></span>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="o_37" class="feed" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><span class="cat-title" data-title="37">Apple<span class="edit-title">rename</span></span>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li class="feed sub"><a data-uid="18" data-fid="11" href="http://appleinsider.com/appleinsider.rss"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=appleinsider.com" class="favicon"><span class="title">AppleInsider - Frontpage News</span><span class="options"><span data-fid="11" class="addcat">+</span><span class="delete">×</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5hDKn/)

**Based on the update**

I think it will be better to use the [toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) option here

```
$("#user-stream-list").sortable({
    update: function () {
        var ids = $(this).sortable('toArray', {
            attribute : 'data-id'
        });
        console.log(ids);
        var oids = $(this).sortable('toArray', {
            attribute : 'data-oid'
        });
        console.log(oids);
        //$("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VgBdU/)

Comment: Thanks I have made changes to the OP to explain what I exactly reaquire

Comment: @Beardy I don't think the serialize method supports two attributes... can you create a third attribute with the desired value... and also share the format of how you want the value

Comment: I don't see how I could update my database without having 2 values passed per list item. I will update my OP with the look of the table

Comment: @Beardy see the update.. you can pass both the array values to the server and access them in order or make it as a pair in client and sent the pair to the server

Comment: @Beardy can't help you much on that... I'm not a PHP guy :(